# PHP regex check if string is latin or cyrillic

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to check if a user input is either in Latin or Cyrillic. I would like to make the user enter a text that is in only Latin or Cyrillic letters. How do I allow one and deny the other? I dont want the user to mix latin and cyrillic. It is only one or the other. I am new to regex and cant figure out a way to do it.
Here is what I have so far.

```
!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z]+|[\p{Cyrillic}]+)$/u", $inputstr)
```

Also, What does "/" at the beginning and the end do? And what does "/u" do?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: At least the question about slashes and the `u` modifier (hint: Unicode starts with the letter `u`) should have been easy to answer from the docs. But the more important question is: What characters may an "all-latin" or "all-cyrillic" string contain? Punctuation? Whitespace? Symbols? Which ones?

Comment: Thanks Tim. the latin and the cyrillic contains only letters and no puncuation, whitespace, or symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation zerkms linked answers some of your questions.

First, what is the `/` at the beginning and end? That's the [delimeter pattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) enclosing your regex.

Second, what is the `u`? That's a [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to treat the pattern string as unicode.

To allow only one type of char, use grouping, as follows: `/^(?:\p{Cyrillic}+|\p{Latin}+)$/u`

That should match either Cyrillic chars or Latin chars, but not both in the same string.

`(?:stuff)` is a grouping [subpattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) that matches but does not capture.

Comment: What does the ? and : do? I would look up the manual but without knowing what they do, I would just waste my time looking for it. And thanks a lot. Works perfectly!

Comment: If I wanted to add space and hyphen, would the regex look like this? /^(?:\p{Cyrillic} -+|\p{Latin} -+)$/u

Comment: then you need a character class. Instead of `\p{Latin}` do `[\p{Latin}\s-]` and the same for the other.

Comment: Thanks. I would vote up your question more than once if it was possible :)